# Android fragment null pointer exception on rootView

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, return-value

Can anybody help me with this I'm using the android navigation fragment template and I'm new-ish to android, I've just started adding some views to the fragment rootView and a TTS engine, but I'm coming up with an error when adding either the onClickListener to a button in my rootView have tried a lot but i just cant pin it down can i ask someone to please have a look through and let me know where i'm going wrong,
here is my code

```
 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements    
 TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech myTTS;
    private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    private EditText Scr;
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,  
false);
        Scr = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);





        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  
 data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
            }
            else {Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();

installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        //check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.UK) == 
TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }







    }

    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        Scr.setEnabled(false);
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
        Button speakButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.speak);
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
    }
```

thanks for any and all help 
and before i could even blink my question has got a -3 would anyone like to suggest why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind moving

```
Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent(); checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA); startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

To the onViewCreated methode?

And where is the part where you setOnInitListener to the fragment implementation?

Comment: i thought it was already in that method? and i set the listener at the top    'public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment implements     
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener'

Comment: OnViewCreated is not the same as OnCreateView. You implement it in the top but you don't set it anywhere.

Comment: thank you @Exception ive implemented your suggestions,(Thank you btw) but im still no closer to solving it still giving me the same null pointer exception

Comment: Which line throws this null pointer exception?

Comment: ive changed the code above to show what ive done, its throwing the null pointer on the edit text, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: It should work unless you have NO view with the id "editText" in the "fragment_main" layout xml

Comment: thank you i had added the edit text to the wrong layout...